# Get the current queryset shown in ChangeList from the ModelAdmin class

Tags: django, django-admin

I need to work in ModelAdmin with the elements shown in the ChangeList, but I don't know how to get the current queryset.
For example, if now the first 100 elements are being shown, I want to work with this set, and if the user pass to the next 100, I want to have the new 100 elements in the set.
Other example is when some user applies some filter.
In my Model Admin I have:

```
list_display = getListDisplay(qs)
```

And I want to pass to `getListDisplay` the current queryset, because depending on it, the list_display will be different.
Is there any current queryset attribute somewhere accessible from ModelAdmin class?

After **UPD 1** I cannot make this works:

```
class YourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(YourAdmin, self).get_queryset()
        return qs

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(YourAdmin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        qs = self.get_queryset()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to the documentation for [ModelAdmin.get_queryset()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset)

Edit in response to your comments:
It seems to me that what you want to do is build the list_display dynamically. Django has a [get_list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_list_display) method for model admin. This method receives the request which you can then pass to get_queryset:

```
class YourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_list_display(self, request):
        qs = self.get_queryset(request)
        '''
        Now build the list_display as a list or tuple
        '''
        .
        .
        return list_display
```

Comment: This is great, but I am still having the same problem: In `qs` I have the whole query (all the elements in the table), not the real subquery shown in the changelist view. It paginates from 1 to 100, from 101 to 200, and so on. I need what exactly is been shown. I have checked [get_pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_paginator) but doesn't return the current elements... Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: @toscanelli: You're welcome. The variables the pagination is being built on should be available in the request object in that `get_list_display` method, so maybe you could use those to construct your list_display rather than the actual queryset?

Comment: That was the key! I got the pagination from the request `request.GET.get(variable)` and with it, I build the list_display. Thank you both, @Павел Тявин and you.

Answer (score 0):

In django admin, there is a thing called **actions**. It is described in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) and works like this:

```
class YourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def make_something(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(status='p')
    actions = ['make_something',]
```

Maybe **queryset** is the thing you need

**UPD 1:** After comment, I understood that you need to modify some attributes of your ModelAdmin ojbect. So you can do that right after initialization:

```
class YourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(YourAdmin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        qs = self.getquery_set()
        // modify your list_display depending on qs
        self.list_display = ['some','fileds','here']
```

Some third-party apps like [xadmin](https://github.com/sshwsfc/django-xadmin) allow you to change **list_display** on the fly, but django doesn't have this feature by default.

Comment: Thank you. I knew this thing, but I believe that this works only with objects selected in the changelist, and what I exactly need is all the objects appearing in the current changelist form.
I edit my question to explain what I need, because I think what @hellsgate isn't helpful for me neither.

Comment: This seems to be very close to my need. But I don't understand this `qs = self.getquery_set()` since I am defining getquery_set as @hellsgate told me [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset)

Comment: do you know what `self` stands for?

Comment: What I mean is that if I define get_queryset like in the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) `get_queryset(self, request)` I don't have that _request_, and if I define the function `get_queryset(self)` (without _request_) it says `'super' object has no attribute 'get_queryset'` in the line `qs = super(YourAdmin, self).get_queryset() `